# Saving a file with the date and time using shell

Tags: python, bash, shell, datetime

I have something in Python which saves a file in the following datetime format:

```
>>> s = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
>>> print s
20121208145544
```

Things have changed slightly and this now needs to be done in shell. Is there a way to get the datetime in exactly the same  format using shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
touch filename_`/bin/date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.txt
```

creates an empty file

```
filename_20130104112845.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`date` command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date), it takes the exact same formatting parameters, preceded by a `+`:

```
date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
>>> z = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
>>> file_ = open(z+'.txt', 'w')
>>> file_.close()
```

This creates 20130104160557.txt.